# JavaScript and Passing Event instance to function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am facing a cross browser issue while trying to pass an event object from an `onclick` event.

Currently, I am doing the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
  var link= list[i];     
  link.onclick = function(el) {  return function () {LinkManager.HandleOnClick(window.event, el); }}(link);
 }
```

Firefox doesn't respect `window.event`. However, how else can I pass it?

I resorted to a "not" clean solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
  var link= list[i];     
  link.onclick =  SomeClickHandler;
 }

function SomeClickHandler(e)
{
  e = e || window.event;
  if (typeof (e) !== 'undefined')
  {
    var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
    LinkManager.HandleOnClick(e, element);
  }
}
```

Can anyone recommend a better way of solving it? I really didn't like the workaround that I did.

Comment: I think your solution is better than the previous one... you are not binding a new function to each element, but you are reusing the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your handler to have access to the `el` variable and the event object when it's called. That's possible and not that hard, but you might want to read up on closures:

```
link.onclick = (function(el)
{
    return function (e)//this function will receive the event object
    {
        e = e || window.event;//for ie
        LinkManager.HandleOnClick(e, el);
    }
})(link);
```

but, to be honest, this is overkill, try this (pun intended):

```
link.onclick = function(e)
{//this refers to `link`, the clicked element
    e = e || window.event;//for ie
    LinkManager.HandleOnClick(e, this);
};
```

or even less code:

```
link.onclick = function(e)
{//this refers to `link`, the clicked element
    e = e || window.event;//for ie
    LinkManager.HandleOnClick.apply(this,[e]);
    //LinkManager.HandleOnClick will receive 1 argument, the event object, and 'this' will point to 'link'
};
```

and even less:

```
link.onclick = LinkManager.HandleOnClick;//this === link, 1 argument: the event object
```

---

That said, you're iterating a list, and attaching an event listener to each individual child element. I'd strongly advise you to use delegaion:

```
if (list.addEventListener)
{
    list.addEventListener('click',LinkManager.HandleOnClick,false);
}
else if (list.attachEvent)
{
    list.attachEvent('onclick',LinkManager.HandleOnClick);
}
else
{
    //use the loop you have now as a last resort
}

//LinkManager.HandleOnClick should start like so:
LinkManager.HandleOnClick = function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;//<- you have the event object here
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;//=== list item: your link variables, your element
    console.log(this);//<-should reference the list element (<ul> || <ol>)
};
```

Anyway, that's how I'd tackle this

Answer (score 0):

```
var handler = function (evt) {
    // do something here
}

if(window.addEventListener) {
    link.addEventListener("click", handler);
} else if(document.attachEvent) {
    link.attachEvent("onclick", handler)
}
```

Comment: I wanted to eventually have my handler to be like this:

Comment: I wanted my handler to  have the following signature. 

var handler = function (evt, arg) {
    // do something here
}

with the approach above, i don't see a way to pass parameters. Secondly, I had to avoid any closure parameter resolution issues by return an anonymous method in the first example.

I was thinking something like this would do. However, that didn't work either. 

function (evt) { return function (arg) { LinkManager.HandleOnClick(evt, arg); } (arg) };

Comment: just for clarity: when using a closure, you pass the argument to the outer function (the one that returns a function. The returned function will be the once receiving the event object: `(function(argument){return function(eventObject){//handle event};})(argumentValue);`